# 16' Penske box truck - do I need to stop a scale?

Tags: usa

I have a 16 foot box truck - do I need to stop at scales?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the state traffic regulations

Comment: @Karlson how are state traffic regulations off topic?  They affect nearly everytraveler in the US to some degree.

Comment: @phoog thing is the op doesn't mention travelling anywhere. For what we know they might use that truck for work.

Comment: @mkennedy, well done for spotting the duplicate. They should give rep for that, but they don't

Comment: @GayotFow I remembered it because I argued about the answers!

Comment: @mkennedy, sometimes it's astonishing when people ferret out a duplicate.  I know the main site has debated badges or rep for it, but the proposal has never gained traction.  Arrogance from the higher ups probably :)

Comment: @phoog Because you normally don't travel in a box truck.  You move in a box truck.

Comment: @Karlson the only time I ever moved in a box truck was one of the more interesting travel experiences I have ever had.